# Help me solve this question from a culture fair IQ test?

Tags: logical-deduction

[image: iq test question]

Cannot wrap my head around these 2, please also tell me what the logic is? For the 2nd one I think it might be a water droplet shape? But not sure about the logic. Thank you[image]

Comment: Can you please reference the IQ test thanks

Comment: @Adam and the folks who answered this:  We have an explicit close reason for unattributed content not created by the poster. Next time please use it.

Answer (score 3):

For (1) I think the answer is:

> C, for the reasons given by [@Matti](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85492/help-me-solve-this-question-from-a-culture-fair-iq-test/85494#85494).

For (2) I think the answer is:

> B

because

> shapes 1&7, 4&8 and 5&6 are mirrors of each other along a central vertical axis. Of the two shapes left, 2 and 3, only 3 has a mirror (which is B), so each shape where possible has a mirror pair. I would have preferred that the X shape was its own mirror conjugate, but I guess not!

Comment: Quick reminder: If you can tell (with reasonable certainty) that the OP is not posting their own content, it's better to point out the attribution/no-plagiarism requirement than to spend time answering a question likely to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is the ...

> last possible item, because this question contains 3 series. The square, the square with a circle, the rectangle, the rectangle with a circle, the triangle and the triangle with a circle. The segments of the circle are always mirrored on the lines of the triangle, square or rectangle.

I guess the second answer is the...

> second possible item, because the item on the top left is divided in two parts, then the right segment is moved to the left and the left segment is moved to the right. The result is the right item at the bottom. The answer could be the second possible item, if this method also works for the top left item.

Comment: Makes sense, although I think for the first one it might be the smaller triangle.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.

Comment: Quick reminder: If you can tell (with reasonable certainty) that the OP is not posting their own content, it's better to point out the attribution/no-plagiarism requirement than to spend time answering a question likely to be closed.